# Shower recess light has a gap

Tags: shower, recessed-lighting

I have a recess light in the shower cabin that went out. I’ve replaced it with a 10W “suitable for damp locations” bulb. Not now the lamp won’t sit flush with the ceiling.

[image]

The spring mechanism seems loose since the light is sort of dangling  no amount of pushing seats it tight.

Q) is it ok to leave as is with that gap?
Or Q) what can I do to tighten the spring?

The light itself looks like this inside:

[image]

[image]

Comment: are there hoocks inside for differnat spring tension

Comment: No hooks as far as I can see. They look like two prongs coming down to base of the bulb from the spring behind the white base plate in the third photo.

Comment: "Is it OK to leave it like this?" Sure, if it doesn't bother you. If the fixture is rated for wet locations, it's not going to let any more wet in hanging down like that than it would otherwise. It seems that it bothers you, though, so really the only question is "How do I fix it?" Please [edit] your question to remove that first part, then include the brand & model of the replacement part so people can look up the installation instructions. BTW- "replaced it with a ... bulb" - did you replace the bulb _only_ or the entire _fixture_?

Comment:  bothers me sure.. the first part is to gauge how much it should bother me; risk vs aesthetic. Your answer is helpful! Thank you. I simply changed the bulb. The previous resident had a generic bulb in there, and i put in a 10 W suitable for damp, not dimmers bulb.

Comment: Does it seat without the bulb? Is the actual can loose inside the ceiling?

Comment: I haven’t tried without the bulb. Not sure what all makes up the can, but the portion in the ceiling is not loose. Just the part attached with the spring. (The cover and assembly attached to it)